# Differentiate XPath from CSS selectors (Regex?)

Tags: regex, xpath, css-selectors

Is it possible to somehow programmatically differentiate a CSS- from an XPath-Selector? I know there are expressions that work in both languages. But in unambiguous cases I would like to find out if it is one or the other syntax.

Edit:

I have an array of strings representing either CSS or XPath-selectors and I would like to programmatically find out which is which (if even possible).

```
selectors = [
  '/bookstore/book[last()]',          // xpath
  '#some-id',                         // css
  '//title[@lang='en']',              // xpath
  '.someclass .someclass[disabled]',  // css
]

// iterate and determine which list to put each selector into somehow ...

css_list = [
  '#some-id',                         // css
  '.someclass .someclass[disabled]',  // css
]

xpath_list = [
  '/bookstore/book[last()]',          // xpath
  '//title[@lang='en']',              // xpath
]
```

If the selector is valid in *both* languages (e.g. `"html"`) it should just be put in either the CSS or the XPATH-list.

Comment: This is kind of a question that community try to close but unfortunately a bounty avoids it.

Comment: @revo, If my question is that stupid it would be nice to know why exactly so I can learn something. I don't think that is too much to ask. "If you cannot do a kind deed, speak a kind word"

Comment: That's my kind word to community. You are asking a question which doesn't provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Requirements are not clear. _I know there are expressions..._ with no further elaboration just means _you should know too otherwise you are not smart enough to answer_. _But in unambiguous cases_ is another statement which leaves reader  lots of questions that makes them guess about different things which may or may not be your intention. Do readers a favor and provide them more details about the problem, your solution and where it does fail.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the clarification. I'll try to better formulate my questions in the future. Sorry for any misunderstandings (English is not my native language).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex is probably not the right tool for this job. Regular expressions can only analyze sentences that are [Chomsky Type 3 grammar (regular grammar)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar). I couldn't find anything related to that subject, but I don't think that XPath or css selectors are regular grammar, because they look too complex, and even if they were the regex would probably look awfully large and difficult to understand and maintain.

You should look for existing parsers, in whatever language you are using, to check if a given expression is valid. For instance in java there is the `javax.xml.xpath.XPath` class that can parse XPath, and for css selectors I found [this CSS Selector Parser](https://github.com/utluiz/parCSSer).

Based on the four examples in your question I've built a simple proof of concept using the libraries that I mentioned:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import br.com.starcode.parccser.Parser;
import br.com.starcode.parccser.ParserException;

public class XPathAndCssTest extends org.junit.Assert {

    @Test
    public void testValidSelectors() {
        assertTrue(isXPath("/bookstore/book[last()]"));
        assertTrue(isCSSSelector("#some-id"));
        assertTrue(isXPath("//title[@lang='en']"));
        assertTrue(isCSSSelector(".someclass .someclass[disabled]"));
    }
    
    public boolean isCSSSelector(String selector) {
        try {
            Parser.parse(selector);
        } catch (ParserException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    public boolean isXPath(String selector) {
        try {
            XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            xPath.compile(selector);
        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

In the `isCSSSelector` and `isXPath` methods, an expression is evaluated against a parser that throws and error if the expression is not valid. Instead of throwing the error I just return false. If everything goes right I return true.

In conclusion, to answer your question, yes, it is possible to programmatically differentiate a CSS from an XPath-Selector, as the code that I've posted proves that.

**NOTE:** This java code was built using maven with the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>br.com.starcode.parccser</groupId>
    <artifactId>parccser</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3-RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.13</version>
</dependency>
```

**NOTE 2:** In you question I noticed you were probably using javascript. A quick search on google showed up some examples of parsers in that language. For instance, [js-xpath](https://github.com/dimagi/js-xpath) for XPath and [scalpel](https://github.com/gajus/scalpel) for css selectors.